# Finite differences Wrong number

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

The list is 1 2 4 8 16 26 42 64 93. A number in this list is wrong.

Finite differences propagation error:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 f(x)&  \Delta^1{f}& \Delta^2{f}& \Delta^3{f} \\ \hline
 f_{0}&  \Delta^1{f_{0}}& \Delta^2{f_{0}}& \Delta^3{f_{0}}+\epsilon \\ \hline
 f_{1}&  \Delta^1{f_{1}}& \Delta^2{f_{1}}+\epsilon& \Delta^3{f_{1}}-3\epsilon  \\ \hline
 f_{2}&  \Delta^1{f_{2}}+\epsilon& \Delta^2{f_{2}}-2\epsilon& \Delta^3{f_{2}}+3\epsilon \\ \hline
 f_{3}+\epsilon&  \Delta^1{f_{3}}-\epsilon& \Delta^2{f_{3}}+\epsilon& \Delta^3{f_{3}}-\epsilon \\ \hline
 f_{4}& \Delta^1{f_{4}}& \Delta^2{f_{4}}& - \\ \hline
 f_{5}& \Delta^1{f_{5}}& -& - \\ \hline
 f_{6}& -& -& -  \\ \hline
\end{array}
And so on.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 f(x)&  \Delta^1{f}& \Delta^2{f}& \Delta^3{f}& \Delta^4{f}& \Delta^5{f}& \Delta^6{f}& \Delta^7{f}& \Delta^8{f} \\ \hline
 1&  1& 1& 1& 1& -5& 15& -35& 70 \\ \hline
 2&  2& 2& 2& -4& 10& -20& 35& -\\ \hline
 4&  4& 4& -2& 6& -10& 15& -& -\\ \hline
 8&  8& 2& 4& -4& 5& -& -& -\\ \hline
 16& 10& 6& 0& 1& -& -& -& - \\ \hline
 26& 16& 6& 1& -& -& -& -& - \\ \hline
 42& 22& 7& -& -& -& -& -& - \\ \hline
 64& 29& -& -& -& -& -& -& - \\ \hline
 93& -& -& -& -& -& -& - \\ \hline
\end{array}

$How\ to\ find\ \Delta^1{f_{0}}=f_{1}-f_{0}$

$\Delta^1{f_{1}}=f_{2}-f_{1} and\ so\ on\ $

$\Delta^2{f_{0}}=\Delta^1{f_{1}}-\Delta^1{f_{0}}$

$\Delta^2{f_{1}}=\Delta^1{f_{2}}-\Delta^1{f_{1}} and\ so\ on\ $

Comment: [This page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) will show you how to type mathematics on this site in a much more readable form using $\LaTeX$ and MathJax.  Try using arrays to achieve the result you want.

Comment: What are the finite differences supposed to be?

Comment: see forward difference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference

Comment: As for the content of your question, it is not clear what pattern you would expect a "corrected" list of numbers should have.  Given any beginning to a sequence, say $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n$ and only given those numbers and not a hint as to the nature of the sequence such as "this sequence is geometric" or "the closed form for this sequence is quadratic" etc... there is never enough information to uniquely determine $a_{n+1}$ as there are uncountably infinitely many sequences starting that way.  Similarly there are plenty of sequences starting how yours does despite "having a wrong number."

Comment: The fact is that from that sequence we construct the finite difference table and we should "see" the propagation of errors

Answer (score 3):

The column $1,-4,6,-4,1$ looks like Pascal's triangle with alternate terms reversed.  If you work diagonally downward from the $6$ (because you portray the differences diagonally) you find the term to fix. If you centered the differences under where they come from it would be right above.  Change the $16$ to $15$ and you have a cubic.

Comment: Yes this what i was looking for can you show me how to work diagonally from 6 to obtain 15?

Comment: I just did it by trial and error, putting your table into a spreadsheet.  The whole system is linear, so once you identify the one to change, just change it by a convenient amount and scale the change.  The fact that the errors are $1$ times Pascal suggests the change should be $1$